# Meteor Email Attachments

Tags: meteor

I've updated my meteor to 1.2, and I'm now trying to use the email attachment feature, but not sure how to.

Meteor's guide says refer to [this](https://github.com/andris9/mailcomposer#add-attachments), but it's not very helpful..

```
if(true == true){
      var dataAttachments = attachment;
      var dataText = 
      "Client Name: " + name + 
      "\rEmail: " + email + 
      "\rPhone: " + phone + 
      "\rCompany: " + company +
      "\rDeliverables: " + deliverables +
      "\rCopywriting: " + copywriting +
      "\rPrint Services: " + print +
      "\rIllustration: " + illustration +
      "\rphotography: " + photography + 
      "\rTimelines: " + timelines +
      "\rBudget: " + budget +
      "\rDescription: " + description;

      Meteor.call('sendEmail', dataText, dataAttachment);
      //throwAlert is my helper method which creates popup with message
      alert('Email sent');
    }else{
      alert('An error occurred. Sorry');
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

and

```
Meteor.methods({
  sendEmail: function (text) {
    check([text], [String]);

    this.unblock();

    Email.send({
      to: 'jaeeun@antarcti.cc',
      from: 'contact@myClientProject.com',
      subject: 'New message from contact form',
      text: text
    });

    Email.send().addAttachment(attachment);
  }
});
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried, and in what way is it not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest installing this package: https://atmospherejs.com/ashutosh/email-att
Then do:

```
var attachments = [];
attachments.push({filename: "xxx", filePath: "xxx"});
var email = {
    from:    "test@gmail.com",
    to:      "test2@gmail.com",
    subject: "Test!",
    text:    "Text!"
    attachmentOptions: attachments
};
Meteor.call('send_one_email_with_attachments', email, function(){});


Meteor.methods({
    send_one_email_with_attachments: function(email){
        this.unblock();
        EmailAtt.send(email);
    };
});
```

This made my life a lot easier after I fought Meteor's built-in email for a while. It even works side-by-side, so you can still use your old non-attachment email functions!

Comment: what do you put in filename: "xxx" for xxx?

Comment: I believe you can use whatever you want for `filename`, keeping in mind to give it the correct extension. I used an external url for `filePath`; you may also be able to specify a file on the server.

Comment: I'm trying to enable the site user send their attachments.

Comment: Sorry; you'll need to be more specific. Where are those attachments? In your database? On their harddrives? On the server? What format are they in? I might not be able to help you though; I know that my solution works when the file is addressable by url, but beyond that I'm not sure.